# Сокет и потоки нужно после каждого обращения клиента закрывать?

Tags: java, сокет

Объясните как делать правильно.
Есть сервер-программа, при запуске запускается сокет сервер, должен ли все время быть открыт сокет и потоки или их нужно после каждого обращения клиента закрывать? Если нужно закрывать, то как тогда в нужный момент их обратно открыть?
Вопрос по клиентской части, аналогичный. Если мне нужно периодически отправлять данные на сервер по средствам сокета, тот же вопрос, нужно ли закрывать открывать сокет и поток?
и вообще, верно ли я делаю, при поднятие сокета

```
  server = new ServerSocket(4004); 
  clientSocket = server.accept(); 
  in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
  out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream()));
```

И существует ли какой-то аналог пулов для БД или это единственно верный вариант работы с сокетами?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Сервер я не закрываю

---

#### Думаю готовый код будет удобнее:

Я так делал:

(когда делал онлайн игру(могу дать ссылку на github))

```
package Server;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import JFrames.JAdmin;
import JFrames.JMesseges;
import Models.Message;

public class Server {

    
    public void main(int ss) {
        Server s = new Server();
        s.go(ss);
    }
    
    private ArrayList<ObjectOutputStream> clientWriters = new ArrayList<ObjectOutputStream>();

    private void go(int ss) {
        try {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Server was started");
            ServerSocket serverSock = new ServerSocket(ss);
            
            while (true) {
                
                Socket clientSocket = serverSock.accept();
                ServerClient client = new ServerClient(clientSocket);
                ObjectOutputStream writer = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
                clientWriters.add(writer);
                Thread t = new Thread(client);
                t.start();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Server was falled:\n" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    
    private class ServerClient implements Runnable {

        ObjectInputStream reader;
        Socket socket;
        
        public ServerClient(Socket clientSocket) {
            try {
                socket = clientSocket;
                reader = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("");
            }
        }
        
        private void sendToOthers(Message message) throws IOException {
            for (int i = 0; i < clientWriters.size(); i++) {
                clientWriters.get(i).writeObject(message);
                clientWriters.get(i).flush();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Message message;
            try {
                while ((message = (Message)reader.readObject()) != null) {
                    sendToOthers(message);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

```
public class Message implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    private String nickname;
    private String message;
    private int id;

    public Message(String nick, String msg, int iD) {
        nickname = nick;
        message = msg;
        id = iD;
    }
    
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public String getNickname() {
        return nickname;
    }
    public int getID() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

```
package Client;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.ConnectException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import Interfaces.Publisher;
import Interfaces.Subscriber;
import Models.Message;

public class Client implements Publisher {
    
    ObjectInputStream reader;
    ObjectOutputStream writer;
    Socket socket;
    String nickname;

    public static int players = 0;
    private ArrayList<Subscriber> observers = new ArrayList<Subscriber>();
    
    @Override
    public void addObserver(Subscriber o) {
        observers.add(o);
        players = observers.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void removeObserver(Subscriber o) {
        observers.remove(o);
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyObservers(Message m) {
        for (Subscriber o : observers) {
            o.update(m);
        }
    }
    
    public Client(String nick) {
        nickname = nick;
    }
    
    public String setUpNetwork(String ip, int ss) {
        try {
            socket = new Socket(ip, ss);
            writer = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            reader = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            IncomingReader ir = new IncomingReader();
            Thread t = new Thread(ir);
            t.start();
            return "Successful connection";
        }catch (ConnectException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ConnectException");
            return e.getMessage();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return e.getMessage();
        }
    }
    
    public boolean sendMessage(String message) {
        Message msg = new Message(nickname, message,0); //FIXME
        try {
            writer.writeObject(msg);
            writer.flush();
            return true;
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            return true;
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    private class IncomingReader implements Runnable {  

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Message message;
            try {
                while (true) {
                    Object o = reader.readObject();
                    if(o.equals("")) {
                    } else {
                        message = (Message) o;
                        notifyObservers(message);
                    }
                } 
            }catch (StreamCorruptedException | SocketException e) {
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
package Interfaces;

import Models.Message;

public interface Publisher {
    void addObserver(Subscriber o);
    void removeObserver(Subscriber o);
    void notifyObservers(Message m);
}
```

```
package Interfaces;

import Models.Message;

public interface Subscriber {
    void update(Message m);
}
```

а это я совал в класс с JFrame:

```
...
final Client client = new Client(name.getText());
String s = client.setUpNetwork(ip.getText(), ss);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, s);
if(s.equals("Successful connection")) {
    client.addObserver(new MessageHandler());
}
...
private class MessageHandler implements Subscriber {

        @Override
        public void update(Message m) {
            try {
                String message = m.getMessage() + '\n';
                text.append(message); // text - это JTextArea
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        
        }
    }
...
```